# Symfony2 form - How to pass data from integer property to checkbox

Tags: forms, symfony

I am doing a form in order to bet on the winner of a match.
The form is the classic one : Match - checkboxes (1, X or 2)

I can make the form when creating a new bet, but i can't make it to edit the bet, with a preselected checkbox.

my controller :

```
public function parierAction()
{

    $matchs = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ParisParisBundle:Matchs')->findAll();
    $user = $this->getUser();

    foreach ($matchs as $match) {

            $pari = new Pari();
            $pari->setMatchs($match);
            $pari->setUser($user);
            $pari->setPari1X2(1);

        $pariss[] = $pari;
    }
    $paris = array ('paris'=>$pariss);

    $form = $this->createForm(new ParisType, $paris);
```

my Types

```
class ParisType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('paris', 'collection', array(
            'type'   => new PariType()));

}

public function getName()
{
    return 'paris_parisbundle_paristype';
}
```

and the PariType, containing the choice with checkboxes

```
class PariType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('pari1X2', 'choice', array(
            'choices'   => array('1' => '1', '3' => 'X', '2' => '2'),
            'required' => false,
            'expanded'  => true,
            'multiple' => true,


        ));

}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Paris\ParisBundle\Entity\Pari',

    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'paris_parisbundle_paritype';
}
```

I made this example as simple as possible.
If I remove the

```
$pari->setPari1X2(1);
```

I will see the checkboxes. pari1X2 property is a small integer. 
But if I let it like this, I got the error :

```
Expected an array.
```

I guess there is a conflict with the integer and the choice, but i can't resolve it.

edit: entities
    class Pari
    {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Paris\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Paris\ParisBundle\Entity\Matchs")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $matchs;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="datePari", type="date")
 */
private $datePari;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="pari1X2", type="smallint")
 */
private $pari1X2;


class Matchs
{
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Paris\ParisBundle\Entity\League")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $league;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Paris\ParisBundle\Entity\Team")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $teamlocal;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Paris\ParisBundle\Entity\Team")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $teamaway;


/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
```

Comment: It sounds like you need a data transformer. Check out the documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html and post back your findings :)

Comment: we need to see your Paris & Matchs Entities